# My prefix isn't a great date, My suffix is a great gate

Tags: riddle, rhyme

- My prefix isn't a great date.
- My suffix is a great gate.
- My infix helps keep order.
- My whole is a disorder.

Hint 1:

> "My prefix is associated with mythical hate." is a more direct first line.

Hint 2:

> "My suffix is a truthful gate." is a more direct second line.

Hint 3:

> "My infix can be the difference between away and home."
>  and
>  "My whole is less a disorder and more a syndrome."
>  are more direct third and fourth lines.

Comment: Can we get a hint?

Comment: Updated with Hint 1, based on your suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New answer!!

> Is it Impostor?

> Imp is a malicious mythical creature

> The 'or' gate... thanks to Luke Rotter for this

> Post also means a job, a job is something that you normally do away from home. In another definition it also helps to keep order (a beam that sticks out of the ground) since a post carries a sign for traffic to keep it under control.

> Impostor is part of Impostor Syndrome.

Comment: I'm afraid this is a little too far-fetched. Try thinking along the lines of Lukas' answer.

Comment: New answer!!!!!

Comment: Yup this is it, good work! Another interpretation of post could be a beam that helps support things (i.e., keep them in 'order') or a goal post keeping the 'away' team from the 'home' team (or vice versa) by preventing them from scoring.

Answer (score 2):

The best I can possibly come up with is

> demonstrator

My prefix isn't a great date

> Dating with a demon might not be the best idea for your own health. It's also mythical as clued by hint #1, and demons are associated with hatred

My suffix is a great gate

> Logical OR gate, also clued by the hint #2 "truthful" (truth table, and maybe the fact that the truth table of the OR gate has three out of four 1s, which represents true as a boolean)

My infix helps keep order

> Strat, common abbreviation for strategy

My whole is a disorder

> A demonstration with many people partaking can result in disarray

Comment: Were you influenced by my interpretation of date?

Comment: @Deepthinker101 I don't think so, maybe subconsciously. I ditched the idea of date as in timestamp right away because I don't know many dates of e.g. disasters that you can abbreviate into sensible letters. So date as in romantic date was the next sensible choice.

Comment: I would be suprised if this was the actual answer

Comment: The last two descriptions seem a little remote

Comment: @Deepthinker101 Yeah I agree. But the first two matched so well with the hints I just had to post this :P I think the whole is meant to be a mental disorder, but I couldn't find one that fits...

Comment: nice thinking, this is definitely the closest answer we've had so far. @Deepthinker101 is correct that the last two explanations seem a little reaching. Keep thinking along these lines though!

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be

> liquor

My prefix isn't a great date.

> LI - lithium acts on the central nervous system to stabilize mood, while this is great for someone bipolar or manic, it could be seen as making an average person boring, and at least not a great date (no excitement, but not bad). It can be associated to mythical hate as people suffering from such illnesses can often hate things or others without reason/anything based in reality (mythical), and it's a common treatment for them.

My suffix is a great gate.

> OR - see @LukasRotter 's answer for explanation

My infix helps keep order.

> quo - quid for quo keeps order, or maintaining the status quo

My whole is a disorder.

> Liquor - while note directly a disorder, liquor/alcohol abuse is a common disorder in many parts of the world.

Maybe a stretch, but best I could come up with |\('.')/| <-- attempted ascii shrug

Comment: Good try ! For the first part, try focusing more on the updated hint than on the original, since it is meant to be more direct (as a rule of thumb). And the disorder part should definitely be more direct. Stay tuned for another hint soon.

Comment: @ShubhamGoenka I'll be looking for the hint, or maybe have a lucky realization before

Answer (score -2):

> Is it frankenstein.

> fr is friday

> ken is knowledge which brings order

> stein (anime fans will get it a masterpiece on time travel stiens gate.)

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I was looking for. I'll be posting another hint shortly.